# Can redstone torches provide enough light to prevent monster spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that redstone torches are dimmer than normal (coal) torches. <strike>I also know that someday torches won't last forever and we will need to craft [lanterns](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lantern).</strike>

But today I got an idea... I have tons of redstone dust, and I was wondering how much light can redstone torches provide. Do they provide enough light to prevent monster spawning? Would it be viable to use redstone torches for general illumination?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the Minecraft wiki:

```
Hostile mobs will spawn at light levels of 7 or below
```

Because Redstone Torches give off a luminescence of 7, redstone torches by themselves do not provide enough brightness to discourage hostile mobs from spawning.

More detailed info about light [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light).